# Change controls of a camera actor in Game Mode

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I'm attempting to follow a beginner tutorial on UE5 but I'm currently stuck very early on.

Since I'm using an AZERTY keyboard I'm trying to change the control of UE to fit my needs, I had no problems re-binding the viewport camera controls, but once I click "Play", the camera actor is only responding to WASD controls, and I cannot find a way to switch it to ZQSD.

The project I'm on is a simple blank Game template, so there is no actual PC when I click play, it's just a camera that I'm trying to control to move around my world.
As suggested in several other posts, I tried going to Edit > Project settings > Engine > Inputs > Axis Mappings and creating a MoveForward mapping for Z with 1.0 scale (and for S with -1.0 scale, on my second attempt) but nothing is doing the trick...

[image]

[image]

Looking for some help on that one, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have not provided an Overridden Pawn for the PlayerController to possess in the GameMode Override default classes. You will have spawned a DefaultPawn.

The DefaultPawn has hard coded Input Controls that cannot be changed.

[image]

I suggest that you create your own Pawn with its own Controls that you can then decide on what Input Keys manage particular Input Actions.